# How to test a directory tree by using node.js?

Tags: node.js, tree, directory

I have to use Node.js to check a directory tree.

I can't find anything about that... Do you have any idea ?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "test a directory tree"? Check the existing structure of a directory? Compare it to an expected tree?

Comment: Yes, I mean comparing it with an expected tree. I found the fs.existsSync function to check if a file exists in a specified tree. but now my problem is to compare 2 filename (with a different extension), for example I have to check file1.java and file1.feature. If you have an idea for the solution, i'd be glad to hear it. Thank you

Comment: I finally found a way to do it using functions specified on stringjs.com Thank you for your answer

Comment: I didn't post any answer yet, was waiting for clarification, but glad to hear you solved it :) post it as an answer here so it can help others.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to check a directory tree (comparing it to an expected tree).

I used the fs.existsSync function to check if a file exists in a specified tree.

I had also to compare 2 filename (with a different extension), for example file1.java and file1.feature. To do that, I used functions specified on stringjs.com